# Monodroid is able to use any default theme?

Tags: themes, xamarin.android

I would like to know if I can use Android default themes in my app to avoid create it manually, and the way to invoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources in Mono for Android are the same as in standard Android applications, including styles and themes. If you wanted to apply the Light theme to your entire application, for example, you could do it by creating an [Application](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.Application) class and specifying the theme in the attribute:

```
[Application(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light"]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
}
```